# Best practice for handling custom server side errors

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue page where i send a request to my API (vue => vuex => axios => api) This API can either send a OK response or a BadRequest with a custom error object.

{ Code (EG USER_NOTFOUND), Type (Parent type EG GENERAL_CODE), PreviousState (Which is the state of the form that was attempting to update on the server) }

I want to create an action (EG popup) based on the response that will give the users the option to force the update and do what is needed to complete it (EG create new user) or to cancel and revert the state of the form.

I have an errorhandler.js that sorts out which type => subtype it is and i would like call the popup from here and somehow link back to the vue page. Is this a good way to do this? Is something like this even possible? Any blogposts or information guiding me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not the best place for this format of questions (maybe reddit or quora?). Can you reformat the question to focus on a specific problem?

Comment: I'd do it via `Vuex`. Since the call is made from Vuex you can handle the request response from there, mutating something like `store.api_err`, and then you can have a component on top level template, that watches if the `api_err` is set, and display the message.